# How to add a fontawesome icon in html according to the value of an input

Tags: javascript, input, font-awesome

Sorry if my question seems stupid as I am a total newbie.

I'm stuck with the following problem.

I need to add a fontawesome icon as the content of an input text according to a very simple condition defined by "if" as follows :

From the js file :

```
if (eval(form.current_weather.value)==1) { tag_box = HERE_I_need_to_place_a_fontawesome_icon1; } 
else if (eval(form.current_weather.value)==2) { tag_box = HERE_I_need_to_place_a_fontawesome_icon2; } 
else {  tag_box1 = ""; }
```

From the html code :

```
Weather <select name="current_weather">
<option value="1">Rainy</option>
<option value="2">Cloudy</option>
<option value="3">Sunny</option>
</select>
```

I have the variable current_weather which is selected from a dropdown in html. Then, according to the entry selected from this dropdown, the variable tag_box will display a different fontawesome icon (#1 or #2) or no icon.

I really don't know how to achieve this. I spent hours trying to understand javascript and testing with classes, remove.class etc but it is a total failure.

Could anyome help me with this, at least some advice. I would have preferred to use PHP but the get and post functions don't return anything which is obvious actually.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

--- edited with the original question as the replies relate to this message. thank you for the members who tried to help me ---

Comment: I would recommend updating your question with your actual html [mcve]. It difficult to make something for your use case based on your descriptions even the one that you added as an answer.

Comment: My message with the description was deleted, I don't know why.

Comment: its probably because it was an answer that wasn't an answer. I read it and it doesn't actually help. If you noticed, every answer that you have gotten is a variant of the same thing and none are working for your use case. That is because we are only presented with one part but there are other parts that we aren't seeing the code for so everyone just has to guess. That is why [mcve] is very important

Comment: Ok I understand. As I said this is very new to me, it was my first post. A little earlier I edited my post. I detailed everything and as I wrote the code works except the final step as I am missing the skills of coding to display the fontawesome icon within the input field. So far this is the value of the variable that is display and not the icon that relates to this value. Thank you for taking the time to place your comments.

Comment: I read about minimal reproductible example but cannot understand. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let weatherSelector = $('select[name="current_weather"]');

weatherSelector.on('change', () =>
{
  let tagBox = $('#tag_box');
  tagBox.find('i.fas').hide();
  
  let selectedValue = parseInt(weatherSelector.find(":selected").val());
  $(tagBox.find('i.fas')[selectedValue]).show();

});

weatherSelector.trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="current_weather">Weather:</label>
<select name="current_weather" id="current_weather">
  <option value="1" selected>Sunny</option>
  <option value="2">Night</option>
  <option value="3">Windy</option>
  <option value="4">Cloudy</option>
  <option value="5">Snowing</option>
  <option value="6">Lightning</option>
  <option value="7">Partial Cloud</option>
  <option value="8">Rainy</option>
</select>

<span id="tag_box">
  <i class="fas"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-wind"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-snowflake"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-sun"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>
</span>
```

Same answer as [@MH BIPUL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166247/8495363) but in Jquery,

lets assume this is you html:

```
<span id="tag_box">
    <i class="fas"></i>
</span>

Weather <select name="current_weather">
<option value="1">Rainy</option>
<option value="2">Cloudy</option>
<option value="3">Sunny</option>
</select>
```

You can download jquery from here (if you don't have it aleady):
https://jquery.com/download/

in you .html file (just befor the  tag closing):

```
/* if you already have jquery don't write this next line */
<script src="<path to jquery.min.js>"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
let weatherSelector = $('select[name="current_weather"]');

weatherSelector.on('change', () =>
{
    let tagBox = $('#tag_box');
    let selectedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);

    if (selectedValue == 1)
        tagBox.find('i.fas').addClass('fa-cloud-rain').removeClass('fa-cloud');
    else if (selectedValue == 2)
        tagBox.find('i.fas').addClass('fa-cloud').removeClass('fa-cloud-rain');
    else
        tagBox.find('i.fas').removeClass('fa-cloud fa-cloud-rain');

});
</script>
```

This code can still be adjusted based on your senario.

Comment: Thank you! I started by testing the 1st version posted here as I sincerely doesn't know anything about jquery even if I think it is installed. Sorry... total newbie here.

Comment: I use wordpress with the tagdiv newspaper theme and jquery is installed. The code I try to implement is on a new page. So I pasted your code instead of the js one but none icon is displayed. Thank for you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: It's good that your application has jquery, I have edited the answer to be more clear, please try it, and tell us if you still facing an issue.

Comment: Now i have aaded a stackoverflow's code snippet, you can run run it by pressing the **Run** button, please don't be confused between the two answers.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I tested the script on a new page so see if it worked and it did. But I cannot apply it to my needs.

Comment: I really like your piece of code but I don't know how to make the <span> with the different icons work with my tagshen1>8 variables as they are "calculated" and don't come from a selector. I'm sure this is a stupid remark but javascript is sincerely a total stranger for me :-).

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, your question is not stupid at all, and it's great that you're trying to learn and solve a problem. To dynamically change the content of an input text based on the selected option in a dropdown and show FontAwesome icons accordingly, you can follow these steps using JavaScript:

1. Include FontAwesome in your HTML: Make sure you have included the FontAwesome library in your HTML file. You can do this by adding the following line in the `<head>` section of your HTML file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
```

This will load the FontAwesome library, which provides a wide range of icons.

2. Modify your JavaScript code: Update your JavaScript code to set the appropriate FontAwesome icon based on the selected option in the dropdown. Here's the updated code:

```js
// Get the <select> element
var selectElement = document.querySelector('select[name="current_weather"]');

// Get the <input> element where you want to display the icon
var tagBox = document.getElementById('tag_box');

// Add an event listener to the <select> element
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = parseInt(selectElement.value);

    if (selectedValue === 1) {
        tagBox.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>'; // FontAwesome icon for rainy
    } else if (selectedValue === 2) {
        tagBox.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>'; // FontAwesome icon for cloudy
    } else {
        tagBox.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the content if the value is not 1 or 2
    }
});
```

3. Update your HTML: Make sure you have an `<input>` element with the id "tag_box" where you want to display the FontAwesome icon:

```html
Weather <select name="current_weather">
    <option value="1">Rainy</option>
    <option value="2">Cloudy</option>
    <option value="3">Sunny</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="tag_box">
```

Now, when you select an option from the dropdown, the corresponding FontAwesome icon will be displayed in the input text box. If the selected option is not 1 or 2, the input box will be cleared.

Remember to adjust the icon classes in the JavaScript code to match the specific icons you want to use from FontAwesome. In this example, I used "fas fa-cloud-rain" for a rainy icon and "fas fa-cloud" for a cloudy icon. You can find more icons on the FontAwesome website and customize the icons as needed.

Comment: Hello, I'm sincerely grateful for your time and help. I didn't receive any notification thus didn't know I received replies on this thread from stackoverflow. I tested your code a few minutes ago. I followed every step but none icon is displayed. I placed the link of the css file at the top of the html file at the right place, then edited the <script></script> content with your js code and then placed the selector and a div to display the input. All is well displayed but the icon doesn't appear even when I change the value in the selector. Any idea ?

Comment: While using the inspector console I get this error : "Uncaught TypeError: selectElement is null"